# Google plus popup box when hovering over thumbnail?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to create a popup box with user profile details on mouseover like you see on google plus. When hovering over a thumbnail a popup appears with the option to add that person into your circle.

It seems kinda simple to do with jQuery but I've been unable to find a simple solution. Most of the plugins I've come across are too complicated and require a lot of tweaking. Any help on how to do this would be greatly appreciated!
[Hover Effect Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHcjs.png)

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to [try something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/h55Kn/5/). It doesn't handle all the cases you'll need (you need the hover to stay active when user enters the popup); but you can work some of those out I hope.

Here's the basic jQuery code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    function getMyContent($img) {
       // do your fancy ajax calls or append your control links and such here
       return $('<p />').append($img.clone()).append('Here is my fancy hoverbox');
    }

    $('#content img').mouseenter(function(e) {
        var $this = $(this), off = $this.offset();
        var pos = {
            // or you could position it relative to the mouse
            top: (e.clientY + 2) + 'px',
            left: (e.clientX + 2) + 'px'
        };
        $('#hoverbox').css(pos)
            .append(getMyContent($this))
            .fadeTo('slow', .95);
    }).mouseleave(function(e) {
        $('#hoverbox').fadeOut('slow', function() { $(this).html(''); });
    });
});
```

UPDATE: [Here is one that handles the hover events](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/h55Kn/7/) on the popup for you (yeah, I'm still messing around with it; why?)

Comment: I like it but it seems a little buggy. There is a weird random doubling of the image in chrome. I will also need the popup to be positioned so it stays open until I mouseout of it.

Comment: The updated popup link stays open until moused out. The image doubling occurs when the mouseenter event occurs again before the mouseleave animation has completed; that should be easy enough for you to solve. There are bound to be little fiddles like this you'll need to make; alternative is to use one of those libs you don't want :)

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate it. I just need to figure out how to fix the bugs :)

Comment: Sure, get it working and show some examples with specific questions; I'm sure someone will help you through them!

Comment: Here's your code [with the Google+ style added to it](http://jsfiddle.net/NathanJohnson/AhVQN/). ;)

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution would be to add a hidden div to the element that wraps around your profile photo.

```
<div class="profile-popup" style="display: none;">
    <!-- Popup info goes here -->
</div>
```

Go ahead and style the div with CSS however you want it to appear, say with absolute positioning at the bottom right corner for the "pop out" effect.  Then register a mouseOver event in jQuery that shows the div:

```
$().ready( function() {
    $('.profile-pic-wrapper').mouseenter( function() {
        $('.profile-popup', this).show( //pass in some animation options here );
    });
    $('.profile-pic-wrapper').mouseleave( function() {
        $('.profile-popup', this).hide( //pass in some animation options here );
    });
});
```

This is just a basic idea (and that code may need to be tweaked a bit). You'll have to add some additional logic to keep the popup open when the user mouses into it, but this should get you started.

The more elegant solution would be to pass JSON data to your jQuery script and have it generate the popup div dynamically on hover, but that is a bit more advanced.

Comment: Thanks, I like yours better though :P

Comment: Thanks I'll have to try it out.